# Visual Studio 2010: Our own datasets are cluttering the toolbox, how to not to show them?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dataset, toolbox

*I have searched and found other people having problems with getting rid of toolbox items, mainly in VS 2008, but have found no answer applicable to my question.*

All datasets we create and use are shown in the toolbox, and we have no use for them being shown there. Similar questions have been answered with suggestions like using "Choose Items", "Delete the dlls", but those answers either don't fit our problem situation or don't work for us.

The toolbox gets really cluttered when each project in the solution gets a tab in the toolbox. And each tab gets one item for every dataset we create and use. As already stated, we have no use for the datasets being shown there and have tried to remove them. The obvious is using "Choose Items" and unselect the datasets, leaving us with empty tabs - which is slightly better but by no means good. But after restarting VS2010, all datasets are back again...

How to be able hide these datasets, and/or whole project tabs, in the toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the tab that you want to remove within the Toolbox window.
Select "Delete Tab"

I also found that removing the files ["toolbox.tbd", toolboxIndex.tbd"] from [C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0] resets the toolbox.